# How to send and receive a structure variable through via pipe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, ipc

Hi I have to send and receive a message which is structure, how is that possible using pipes

My message is like this

```
typedef struct{
char[20] myMessage,
int      count,
char[10] address
} sendMessage;
```

I know I can send string messages using writefile/readfile, but how can I send a structure variable.

Comment: Exactly the same way, in this case, just pass the address of your sendMessage struct to writefile (and readfile at the other end).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with usual calls to `WriteFile` on one side and `ReadFile` on another. It's important to remember that they can write and read less bytes than requested, so they should be used in a loop until all data are received/transferred.

For fixed-size reads and writes, I sometimes find convenient re-wrapping the pipe handle/descriptor into a `FILE*` structure, so short reads and short writes are handled by C runtime library. On Windows, it's done in two stages: `_open_osfhandle` to get a CRT *lowio* file descriptor for a handle, and then `_fdopen` to get a `FILE*` for a lowio descriptor. (Warning: use `_O_BINARY` for `_fdopen` to ensure the absence of newline translation).